# Animate CroppedBitmap SourceRect Y property

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to animation for wpf image in Int32Rect Y value change.
How to set my wpf Image DependencyObject (Int32Rect) value?

Example:

```
<Image Height="25" Width="25" Name="image3">
        <Image.Source>
            <CroppedBitmap Source="/LoadingCircle;component/Images/loading_circle24.png">
                <CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
                    <Int32Rect X="0" Y="0" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                </CroppedBitmap.SourceRect>
            </CroppedBitmap>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides that you can not animate the properties of an `Int32Rect` struct instance, you can also not animate the properties of the CroppedBitmap class.

Although `SourceRect` is a dependency property, its value can only be set during initialization of a CroppedBitmap instance. The reason is that the class implements the `ISupportInitialize` interface.

See the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> CroppedBitmap implements the ISupportInitialize interface to optimize initialization on multiple properties. Property changes can occur only during object initialization. Call BeginInit to signal that initialization has begun and EndInit to signal that initialization has completed. After initialization, property changes are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

An Int32Rect is a struct.

Hence not a Dependency Object, which would be necessary before you'd be able to animate any of those properties.

I'm not sure whether SourceRect is a dependency property but I suspect that is probably academic.

I think your current approach is unlikely to work.

You could consider animating a clip on the image.

That itself is tricky because the animation will only work within the starting bounds of the geometry you give it. You would probably need some part of the geometry to extend the bounds.

Or.

You could do something else.

I guess this is a loading animation and maybe your requirement is not fixed in stone.

Comment: This example program:[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uY8Oj_fL906Z-q2j2LFY6KBGWX-uxnAR
My loading circle I want put on ListView Item.